# jQuery Position Top Bouncing Up/Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed position widget that moves upwards once a threshold is met (when it hits the footer) to stop it overlapping.

**CSS**

```
.game_widget {top:110px}
```

**Jquery**

```
function scrolling() {
    var $fixedpos = $(".game_widget").offset().top + $('.game_widget').height();
    var $footerpos = $("footer").offset().top - 25;

    if ($fixedpos > $footerpos) {
        $('.game_widget').animate({
            top: 0
        }, 250)

    } else {
        $('.game_widget').animate({
            top: 110
        }, 250)
    }

};

$(window).on('scroll', $.throttle(350, scrolling));
```

As you can see above, if $fixedpos > $footerpos it moves .game_widget upwards by 110px which also reduces $fixedpos by 110px, meaning that the moment the if statement is true, it also becomes false. The result is a bouncing between top 0 and top 110.

I am wracking my brains for a simple solution but it's not clicking. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just made fiddle to emulate here: http://jsfiddle.net/c6y85L88/2/ please advise: what is actually your problem?